# ElasticSearch - copy_to with dynamic template

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, dynamic

Following up my previous question: [ElasticSearch overriding mapping from text to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586864/elasticsearch-overriding-mapping-from-text-to-object/52587938)

I have an index template:

```
{
"template" : "project.*",
  "order" : 100,
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "message_field": {
        "mapping": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "match": "message"
      },
      "message_properties": {
        "path_match":   "message.*",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which basically creates new fields for everything under "message" field. I am doing this because "message" field is mapped as a string in another index template and I am overriding it.

Sample document:

```
{
  "level": "30",
  ...
  "kubernetes": {
    "container_name": "data-sync-server",
    "namespace_name": "alitest03",
    ...
  },
  "message": {
    "tag": "AUDIT",
    "requestId": 1234,
    ...
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

This works fine, but it ends up creating top level fields like "tag" and "requestId".
I don't want to pollute the top level and would like to have fields like "audit.tag", "audit.requestId".

Tried using `copy_to` like this, but I don't see any "audit.*" fields:

```
{
  "template" : "project.*",
  "order" : 100,
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "message_field": {
        "mapping": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "match": "message"
      },
      "message_properties": {
        "path_match":   "message.*",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "copy_to" : "audit.{name}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A sample search result when using the template above with `copy_to` is below. I don't see any "audit.*" fields.

```
{
  "timestamp": "October 15th 2018, 15:46:15.994",
  "_id": "YmI1NDRjMTgtZTY3Ni00ZGUxLTk2NDMtOTJhZjk3ZWU1YTJj",
  "_index": "project.alitestproj02.aa564e69-c643-11e8-af2a-fa163e4c9c9e.2018.10.15",
  "_score": "",
  "_type": "com.redhat.viaq.common",
  ...
  "kubernetes.container_name": "data-sync-server",
  "kubernetes.namespace_name": "alitestproj02",
  ...
  "message": "{\"level\":30,\"time\":1539607575994,\"pid\":19,\"hostname\":\"data-sync-server-6-pxcsm\",\"tag\":\"AUDIT\",\"msg\":\"\",\"requestId\":20355,\"operationType\":\"query\",\"parentTypeName\":\"Meme\",\"path\":\"allMemes.866.owner\",\"success\":true,\"parent\":{\"_type\":\"meme\",\"photourl\":\"photo472\",\"owner\":\"owner35\",\"likes\":0,\"_id\":\"zzEnLAQmQeuTC1mj\",\"createdAt\":\"2018-10-15T11:58:33.896Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2018-10-15T11:58:33.896Z\",\"id\":\"zzEnLAQmQeuTC1mj\"},\"arguments\":{},\"dataSourceType\":\"InMemory\",\"v\":1}\n",
  "requestId": "20355",
  "tag": "AUDIT",
  ...
  "v": 1
}
```

Comment: could you past a search result when using this template? I don't reproduce the problem in my environment. Could you precise what you mean by "but it ends up creating top level fields like "tag" and "requestId"". Are you sure there is no other template with a copy_to clauses that could be responsible for this behavior?

Comment: @PierreMallet thanks for checking it. I updated the question with a search result now. I checked the index template that I override. There are many things in it, but it doesn't use "copy_to". It is here actually: https://github.com/openshift/origin-aggregated-logging/blob/master/elasticsearch/index_templates/com.redhat.viaq-openshift-project.template.json

Comment: Looking to your search result, the template to handle "message" as an object is not working since your still have the json representaiton. I fixed my answer in the previous question cause the syntax was wrong. Can you recheck it and test gain please ?

Comment: @PierreMallet unfortunately it didn't make any difference. thanks for your help